# How to correctly handle exception when multiple exceptions of same type can occur

Tags: python, exception

In the script I'm writing I have this piece of code:

```py
exports_list = [file for file in os.listdir(self.export_folder) 
                if file.endswith('.csv')]
dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(item, fuzzy=True) for item in exports_list]
```

It all works fine, but from my testing I know that the second line can raise two different cases of `ValueError`: one will occur if the list `exports_list` is empty and the other - if `dateutil.parser.parse` doesn't recognise date format or can't find date in strings at all.

As a result I need to handle two similar exceptions on the same line of code. At the moment what I've done is manually raise an exception if `exports_list` is empty and then handle the second exception when executing the second line, but this does look overly complicated:

```py
exports_list = [file for file in os.listdir(self.export_folder) 
                if file.endswith('.csv')]

if not exports_list:
    print('Script will now terminate. Check log for more details.\n')
    with open(self.log, 'a+') as file:
        file.write(f'{dt.datetime.now()}:\n')
        file.write('No .csv files found in bmf_exports folder.\n')
        file.write('\nFile(s) not found or was not accessible.\n')    
    raise ValueError('No .csv files found in bmf_exports folder.')

try:
    dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(item, fuzzy=True) for item in exports_list]
except ValueError:
    print('Parser not able to extract dates from file names.\n')
    print('Script will now terminate. Check log for more details.\n')
    with open(self.log, 'a+') as file:
         file.write(f'{dt.datetime.now()}:\n')
         file.write('Parser was not able to extract date(s) from file names.\n')
         file.write('Make sure export file names include date in format: ')
         file.write('yyyymmdd ')
    sys.exit()
```

What would be a better way to handle exceptions in this case?

Comment: You aren’t *handling* two different exceptions here—you’re creating one of them, and I tend to question it on the grounds that vacuous success is still success (outside of a user interface where it may be presumed to indicate a mistake).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm raising one of the exceptions myself, but if I didn't the second line of the code could create either of these two and in that case if I just used ```except ValueError:``` I wouldn't know which particular exception I'm getting and, therefore, wouldn't be able to provide appropriate information for the log. This is why I decided to raise the first exception and handle the second one if it comes up. That way at least I know for sure what is failing.

Comment: As given, your list comprehension will simply produce `dates=[]` if `exports_list` is empty, as it should.

Comment: Actually, true. But still though, I don't want the script to continue as normal if there are no files in the folder, i.e. if the list ends up being empty. I was also thinking of trying and ```assert``` that folder is not empty, but this will be essentially the same, just throwing a different exception.

Comment: It still seems to invalidate your question: if you want to detect something (such as an empty list), do so, but that doesn’t have much to do with disambiguatung exceptions.